# What are the current java search options like Hibernate Search or Compass?

Tags: java, search, full-text-search, lucene

With Compass going the way of the dodo (or at least no longer being actively developed), I wonder what other technologies there are that fill a similar role. I'm aware of Hibernate Search, but nothing else really. It seems the direction things are going is towards full indexing agnostic of entities and relationships. Are there other technologies that are worth looking into? Are there benefits to using something more agnostic like Solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never ended up finding any better in-app solutions other than Compass and Hibernate Search. We implemented search with Compass. In retrospect, I find it hard to get answers to my questions and while it works respectably well, I can't help but think that in-app searching is not the way to go. While it's not necessarily a great idea to muck up your environment with several interconnecting applications, from the in-app search land the grass is certainly greener looking over in the Solr pasture (and the ElasticSearch one for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

Solr is awesome. I don't know your exact use case, but solr will probably handle it.

Comment: I think Solr's DataImportHandler may fit the bill if you want incremental indexing of database entities.

Answer (score 0):

There is always solrj 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj